# Access local variable from the global context?

Tags: javascript, closures

```js
function wrapValue(n) {
  var localVariable = n;
  return function() { return localVariable; };
}

var wrap1 = wrapValue(1);
var wrap2 = wrapValue(2);
console.log(wrap1());
// → 1
console.log(wrap2());
// → 2
```

In this example how is it allowed to access **`localVariable`**, which is local to **`wrapValue()`** function, from the *global* environment?
The book, included this example, stated the reason as follows:
*"multiple instances of the variable can be alive at the same time".*
But I didn't understand.

Comment: It's called a closure,..  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: localvariable is a local variable, which will be created for each method invocation. You are exposing this variable using closure.

Comment: It's closures, JavaScript has access to all the variables in the parent scope..

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll read about it.

Comment: The important thing is that `localVariable` is not local to the function (definition), but rather local to each *call* of `wrapValue()`

Answer (score 0):

Your function sets a private value (localVariable) when called and returns it immediately so you can assign it to a another variable without change the private var inside function.